# How to align cells in a grid?

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment

I would like to align the text in the gauge such as the label "AKs" is in the center of the gauge and the value (60) is in the upper right corner with a smaller font.  How can I achieve this? I tried playing with the Alignment option and SpanFromLeft and related functions with no success.

Thanks.

```
bar = VerticalGauge[#1, {0, 100}, GaugeMarkers -> "ScaleRange", 
    GaugeStyle -> {Green, GrayLevel[1]}, 
    TicksStyle -> None, GaugeFrameSize -> None, ScalePadding -> None, 
    ImageSize -> 50, AspectRatio -> 1, LabelStyle -> None, 
    Epilog -> 
     Text[Grid[{{"", Style[#1, Italic, Small]}, {Style[#2, Bold], 
         ""}}], Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]], ImagePadding -> 0, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False] &;
bar[60, "AKs"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
bar = VerticalGauge[#1, {0, 100}, GaugeMarkers -> "ScaleRange", TicksStyle -> None, 
                        GaugeFrameSize -> None, ScalePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 150, 
                        AspectRatio -> 1, LabelStyle -> None, ImagePadding -> 0, 
                        PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False,
                        Epilog -> {Text[Style[#2, 25, Bold], Center], 
                                   Text[Style[#, 15], {Right, Top}, {Right, Top}]}, 
       ] &;
bar[50, "AKs"]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes perfect! Thanks. I didn't know how to specify the Epilog.

Comment: @dabd Think about `Epilog->stuff` like it is just `Graphics[stuff]`. Good luck.